# Firefox 67 redirects to https from IIS

Tags: windows, firefox, https, redirection, iis

I seem to have a rather specific issue that I haven't been able to fix.
since the last Firefox update (67.0) Firefox seems to redirect requests to a local corporate site to https.
Because  this site doesn't use https we are then welcomed by a HSTS error.
The redirect occurs for a dns "search", the redirect however doesn't occure for a different binding "search.companyname.local", the IIS webserver also contains  sites with other single name domains ("tools" for example) which have the same configuration, 2 bindings, one for the single name, one with ".companyname.local" added. These however don't get a redirect to https from firefox.

The version of IIS used is 8.5.9600.16384

Would you have any suggestions how we could resolve the issue?
Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at these. They are older, but some of the same fixes and troubleshooting techniques might apply. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30532471/firefox-redirects-to-https https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38754131/firefox-redirects-localhost-to-https https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25277457/google-chrome-redirecting-localhost-to-https/28586593#28586593

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I found the answer to my problem.
Apparently Firefox added http://search to their HSTS preload list:

https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/security/manager/ssl/nsSTSPreloadList.inc

https://hstspreload.org/?domain=search

So it seems like there isn't really going to be a way for me to avoid this issue. I'll have to start using a different domain name.